# Emacs Lisp performance regression testing

Tags: testing

I'm trying to find a way to implement ERT tests for performance of some elisp code. For that to work I need to have a stable performance metric.

Is there a stable performance metric I could use?

It is okay if Emacs version is fixed.

My attempt is here: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-mode/pull/1259/commits/581dc7b31931710da00c592f3ce049ef579de04b